# Django - How to pass several arguments to the url template tag

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

In my urls.py I have:

```
(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/section/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 
    'paper.views.issue_section_detail', 
    {}, 
    'paper_issue_section_detail'
),
```

and I'm trying to do this in a template:

```
{% url paper_issue_section_detail issue.pub_date.year,issue.pub_date.month,issue.pub_date.day,section_li.slug %}
```

but I get this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError
Caught an exception while rendering: Reverse for 'paper_issue_section_detail' with arguments '(2010, 1, 22, u'business')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

However, if I change the URL pattern to only require a single argument it works fine. ie:

```
(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', 
    'paper.views.issue_section_detail', 
    {}, 
    'paper_issue_section_detail'
),
```

and:

```
{% url paper_issue_section_detail issue.pub_date.year %}
```

So it seems to complain when I pass more than a single argument using the 'url' template tag - I get the same error with two arguments. Is there a different way to pass several arguments? I've tried passing in named keyword arguments and that generates a similar error.

For what it's worth, the related view starts like this:

```
def issue_section_detail(request, year, month, day, slug):
```

How do I pass more than a single argument to the url template tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem lives in the `/(?P<month>\d{2})/` part of your url configuration. It only allows exactly two digits (`\d{2}`) while `issue.pub_date.month` is only one digit.

You can do either allow also one digit in the URL (but this will violate the principle of unique URLs, `/2010/1/...` would be the same as `/2010/01/...`) or pass two digits to the month argument in your url templatetag.
You can use the `date` filter to achieve a consistent formating of date objects. Use the url tag like this:

```
{% url paper_issue_section_detail issue.pub_date|date:"Y",issue.pub_date|date:"m",issue.pub_date|date:"d",section_li.slug %}
```

Look at the month and day argument: It will be always displayed as two digits (with a leading zero if necessary). Have a look at the [documentation of the now tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#now) to see which options are possible for the `date` filter.

Comment: That sounds great - I don't really want to have change the possible formatting for the URL. But when I do issue.pub_date.month|date:"m" then an empty string gets passed to the URL/view.

Comment: You're right - I'm sorry. I obviously had it wrong in the original post. I corrected the `url` tag. You must use `issue.pub_date|date:"m"` instead of `issue.pub_date.month|date:"m"`. The `date` filter operates on `datetime` objects (the pub_date attribute) and not on integers (the pub_date.month attribute).

Comment: Doh, of course, I should have spotted that too. Thanks loads for the help Gregor.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue (I'm using Django 1.3.1) and tried Gregor Müllegger's suggestion, but that didn't work for two reasons:

- there should be no commas between year, month and day values
- my class-based generic view seems to take only keyword arguments

Thus the only working solution was:

```
{% url news_detail slug=object.slug year=object.date|date:"Y" month=object.date|date:"m" day=object.date|date:"d" %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your month expression is `(?P<month>\d{2})`, but you're sending it the argument `1`. The `1` doesn't match `\d{2}`, so the url resolver isn't finding your view.

Try changing the month expression to `\d{1,2}` (or something to that effect).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion Seth - I hadn't made the connection between the regexp and what I was trying to pass to it. But I didn't want to loosen the restriction on the URL, so I'm now changing the format of what I pass in, using Gregor Müllegger's suggestion.