# How to pass several arguments to the url template tag with variable sent from views.py

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

It seems to be pretty easy but it don't work at all.

I am hoping that someone will find the trick!

Anyway, in the django documentation, there is this script which is okay for one argument and does not work with several :

```
<a href="{% url 'news.views.year_archive' 2012 %}">2012 Archive</a>
{# Or with the year in a template context variable: #}
<ul>
{% for yearvar in year_list %}
<li><a href="{% url 'news.views.year_archive' yearvar %}">{{ yearvar }} Archive</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And for me :

```
<a href="{% url 'home.views.something' var1 var2 %}">{{var1}} {{var2}} Something</a>
```

does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: are we talking about URLs or templatetags here ?

Comment: This all depends on what the url pattern for `home.views.something` looks like. So post your `urls.py`.

Comment: can you paste your views snippet here?

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to send the variables, it works !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Comment: We need to be able to see your urls if we can comment on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - How to pass several arguments to the url template tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119463/django-how-to-pass-several-arguments-to-the-url-template-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Show your urls.py

If you want to push several argument, Django must know what to do with them through urls.py.

```
url(r'^(?P<obj_pk>[\d]+)/(?P<user_pk>[\d]+)/$', ....
```

In these we can push something objects primary key and users pk, or something else.